# How to split rows with respect to date?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a table like this:

```
d = {
    "person_id" : [10,10,10,10,20,20],
    "type" : ["Exit", "Enter", "Exit", "Enter", "Exit", "Enter"],
    "exit_date": ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-05", "2022-01-07", "2022-02-01", "2022-02-05"]
}
pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I wanto convert dataframe into this:

```
d = {
    "person_id":[10, 10,20],
    "Exit": ["2022-01-01","2022-01-05", "2022-02-01"],
    "Enter": ["2022-01-02","2022-01-07", "2022-02-05"]
}
pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Thanks.

Comment: For each `person_id` are always pairs `Exit, Enter` ?

Comment: it is not exit_date. it is date. sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> df.assign(index=df.groupby(['person_id', 'type']).cumcount()) \
      .pivot(['index', 'person_id'], 'type', 'exit_date') \
      .reset_index(level=1).to_dict('list')

{'person_id': [10, 20, 10],
 'Enter': ['2022-01-02', '2022-02-05', '2022-01-07'],
 'Exit': ['2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-01-05']}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is just an alternative to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70618356/16343464). Using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html), one can pass a grouper directly:

```
(df.pivot_table(index=[df.groupby(['person_id', 'type']).cumcount(), 'person_id'],
                columns='type', values='exit_date', aggfunc='first')
   .droplevel(0).reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
type  person_id       Enter        Exit
0            10  2022-01-02  2022-01-01
1            20  2022-02-05  2022-02-01
2            10  2022-01-07  2022-01-05
```